# In CakePHP, how can you determine if a field was changed in an edit action?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the `cacheCounter` in `CakePHP`, which increments a counter for related fields.

Example, I have a Person table a Source table. Person.source_id maps to a row in the Source table. Each person has one Source, and each Source has none or many Person rows.

`cacheCounter` is working great when I change the value of a source on a person. It increments `Source.Person_Count`. Cool.

But when it increments, it adds it to the destination source for a person, but doesn't remove it from the old value. I tried `updateCacheControl()` in `afterSave`, but that didn't do anything.

So then I wrote some code in my model for `afterSave` that would subtract the source source_id, but it always did this even when I wasn't even changing the `source_id`. (So the count went negative).

My question: Is there a way to tell if a field was changed in the model in `CakePHP`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To monitor changes in a field, you can use this logic in your model with no changes elsewhere required:

```
function beforeSave() {
    $this->recursive = -1;
    $this->old = $this->find(array($this->primaryKey => $this->id));
    if ($this->old){
        $changed_fields = array();
        foreach ($this->data[$this->alias] as $key =>$value) {
            if ($this->old[$this->alias][$key] != $value) {
                $changed_fields[] = $key;
            }
        }
    }
    // $changed_fields is an array of fields that changed
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i'm not clear on callbacks. doesn't this function need to be called in the controller? how would i implement this?

Comment: @MikeS. You would add it to the models class.

Comment: How do get these fields in the controller? Or should I save it in the Model itself? Actually, I am saving the log of Changed fields only.

Answer (score 8):

With reference to ***Alexander Morland*** Answer.

How about this instead of looping through it in before filter.

```
$result = array_diff_assoc($this->old[$this->alias],$this->data[$this->alias]);
```

You will get key as well as value also.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ->isDirty() in the entity to see if a field has been modified.

```
// Prior to 3.5 use dirty()
$article->isDirty('title');
```

check the doc: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#checking-if-an-entity-has-been-modified

Comment: AFAIK, the mere fact of setting a value (new or not) will flip isDirty() to true. Is there a way to have it compare the content and not set it to true if the content is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Edits happen infrequently, so another select before you do the update is no big deal, so, fetch the record before you save, save it, compare the data submitted in the edit form with the data you fetched from the db before you saved it, if its different, do something.

Answer (score 0):

In the edit view, include another hidden field for the field you want to monitor but suffix the field name with something like "_prev" and set the value to the current value of the field you want to monitor. Then in your controller's edit action, do something if the two fields are not equal. e.g.

```
echo $form->input('field_to_monitor');
echo $form->hidden('field_to_monitor_prev', array('value'=>$form->value('field_to_monitor')));
```

Comment: this isnt a very secure way of doing things. anyone with firebug can change the values of the _prev fields. In my oppinion it better to compare with the actual database to check for changes. see my answer

Answer (score -1):

See if the "save" uses some sort of DBAL call that returns "affected rows", usually this is how you can judge if the last query changed data, or if it didn't. Because if it didn't, the affected rows after an UPDATE-statement are 0.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually thinking if the value changed from before the edit action to after the edit action, pre-save to sql.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, do you want to avoid the SQL call?

Answer (score -1):

You can call getAffectedRows() on any model class.

From class Model :

```
/**
 * Returns the number of rows affected by the last query
 *
 * @return int Number of rows
 * @access public
 */
    function getAffectedRows() {
        $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);
        return $db->lastAffected();
    }
```

Comment: This is not what the questions was asking. Your method would only say IF the data was changed, but not "what" fields were changed.